# ruby on rails: relation between parameters passed to controller and cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, controller

I have this application showing the problem

http://strong-sunrise-4122.herokuapp.com/movies

Try

1. sort by title
2. select some rating and refresh
3. sort by date --> does not work!!

the parameters that are passed to the controller do NOT contain "sort=date" but still "sort=title" how it is possible? However if I remove the cookie in the browser
the link works again. Sorry if this a stupid question. Actually I store some state
in the session, do not touch at all any cookie structure. attached is the "haml" code

```
-#  This file is app/views/movies/index.html.haml
%h1 All Movies
=form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do
  Include:
  - @all_ratings.each_pair do |rating, set|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", true, set
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => 'ratings_submit'
%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{:class => miohelp("title")}= link_to 'Movie Title' , "/movies?sort=title" , :id => "title_header"
      %th Rating
      %th{:class => miohelp("date")}= link_to 'Release Date' , "/movies?sort=date",:id => "release_date_header"
      %th More Info
  %tbody
    - @movies.each do |movie|
      %tr
        %td= movie.title 
        %td= movie.rating
        %td= movie.release_date
        %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)

= link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path
```

Comment: show the code that generates the link!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that in your controller you gave the session contents a higher priority than the incoming parameters. I mean by higher priority is that you are checking the session contents first which redirects the page to a certain url with the parameters you saved in the session. So please could you show up you controller code of the action `index`?